# how to save the array values as each record in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I save the following array values in my sql table?

```
Array (
   [0] => "/path/to/file/file_name1.jpeg"
   [1] => "file_name1.jpeg"
)
Array (
   [0] => "/path/to/file/file_name2.jpeg"
   [1] => "file_name2.jpeg"
)
```

Following is my table structure,

```
id - int - auto inc
path - varchar(200)
name - varchar(50)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert an array of data with `insert()` method:

```
$data = [
    ['path' => '/path/to/file/file_name1.jpeg', 'name' => 'File 1'],
    ['path' => '/path/to/file/file_name2.jpeg', 'name' => 'File 2'],
    ['path' => '/path/to/file/file_name3.jpeg', 'name' => 'File 3'],
];

Model::insert($data);
```

Or:

```
....
DB::table('some_table')->insert($data);
```

Comment: Thanks @alexey, I am returning that array value from function. Am passing that returned value to save into database. Pls suggest me how to pass that array value to save into database.

Comment: I guess you should create new question, describe the situation and post some code, so we'll be able to help you with that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` and `create` method as:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    ModelName::create(['path' => $value[0], 'name' => $value[0]]);
}
```

Remember to add `path` and `name` in your model's fillable attribute.

Comment: This will work, but this will create DB query for each insertion.

Comment: It's use full when you have an observer for `create` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple values with the following

```
$data = array(
    array('name'=>'value', 'path'=>'value'),
    array('name'=>'value', 'path'=>'2048'),
    //...
);

Model::insert($data);
```

You can find more here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#inserts

Comment: if you want to update timestamps you will have to pass
'created_at'=> $now,
'modified_at'=> $now

Hope it will help